# Extending a linearly independent set into a basis: 2 methods?

Tags: linear-algebra

We learned in class today:

If $S$={$\overrightarrow v_{1},...\overrightarrow v_{k}$} is a linearly independent set and $\overrightarrow w \not \in S$ then $S'$=$S$+{$w$} is linearly independent.

Why is this technique better than just checking if $S$ $\cup$ {$w$} is linearly independent?

Comment: First of all, you need that $\vec{w}\notin \text{span} (S)$, not just that it's not in $S$.

Comment: The advantage is that you don't re-check the linear independence of the vectors in $S$, you only need to check that they cannot express $\vec{w}$ as a linear combination.